# Inserting a numeric value into a where statement

Tags: r, r-dbi

I have the following code that works pretty smoothly:

```
 sql_cag <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM `CAG_table` WHERE `comp_id` = 1");
 df <- dbGetQuery(con, sql_cag)
```

What I would like to do now, however, is to replace the `1` by a parameter. So like this:

```
 sql_cag <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM `CAG_table` WHERE `comp_id` ='%a'", competitie_id);
 df <- dbGetQuery(con, sql_cag)
```

With a parameter competitie_id

```
 competitie_id <- 1
 competitie_id <- as.numeric(competitie_id)
```

But this returns an empty dataframe. So somehow, something seems to go wrong with the '%a'. Any thoughts where this might go wrong?

Comment: Your first SQL statement compares comp_id to 1 whereas the second compares it to '0x1p+0' assuming that competitie_id is 1.  Use %d, not %a and remove the single quotes.  You could also use fn$ in the gsubfn function which allows quasi-perl style string interpolation.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck that works. Thanks!